# Chrome Extension: Redirect a request without changing the address bar

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm able to use the webRequest API to do this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        var domain = details.url.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i)[1];
        var redir = details.url.replace(domain, 'localhost');
        return {redirectUrl: redir};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Typing anything into the address bar will redirect to localhost, like it's supposed to. The problem is, I don't want the address bar to change. I'd like it to still say whatever URL I typed in, while still redirecting the request.

Is this possible?

Comment: that would be a huge security risk... you want someone to think they're on a bank website and get redirected without changing the address bar?? think about what you are asking

Comment: Just because it's a bad idea doesn't mean the question shouldn't be answered.

Comment: Why not instead of actually navigating to your other page, just XHR it, wipe the dom, and dump your new page in there

Comment: I wasn't saying I won't answer @JustinLardinois - I was explaining why browsers would never allow that.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of, that it wasn't possible for security reasons. Unfortunately, neither is modifying a hosts file on a Chromebook without enabling developer mode and disabling auto-updates, which is why I'm working on this extension. Someone developing a bank website hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet may very well want to think they're on a bank website (or, rather, the underlying code of the bank website wants them to think they are). Simply adding a Hosts header is enough to do this, but causing the browser's address bar to change isn't aesthetically ideal. Not a catastrophe.