# Redirect request without affecting visual address with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to redirect requests with a key extension in the URL (e.g. `.x` here) to a custom address, almost as if the host is a registered domain (this will later look up the IP of the custom domain). Currently I have a very simple extension like so:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
  return {
    redirectUrl: 'https://example.com', 
  }
}, {
  urls: [
    '*://*.x/*',
  ],
}, [
  'blocking',
]);
```

but this causes the address in the address bar to change. How could one do the same without changing the address bar?

This should also make all relative links and such in the page link to the original address' host (with the `.x` extension), for example clicking `<a href="/page.html">` on a page at `https://example.x` would go to `https://example.x/page.html`, once again triggering the extension.

There seems to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387823/chrome-extension-redirect-a-request-without-changing-the-address-bar) but it seems to have never gotten properly answered. For me, security is not really a concern, it's just a hobby thing. (I'd think the requirement of the extension removes the risk anyway)

Comment: This is intentionally not possible.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hmm, I thought I saw a scambaiter using an extension to do a similar thing (redirect a domain to his fake bank site to pretend to give scammers money) but there must've been more to it then.

Comment: They could host the original site inside an iframe but it won't work if the site checks `window === top`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I believe they did have the domain reserved, actually (the domain just contained the text "not available in your region" and I thought it only existed so that it could be seen as valid from outside). So if I understood this correctly, doing what I want actually needs the domain to be real, and you just practically replace the entire contents? (making the extension pointless)

Comment: Extension might be helpful to strip `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header from sites.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I'll just have to work with the current redirection and keep the extension as a mere memorable shortcut to the target addresses. Thanks for the info, anyway.